# How can i use *ngFor with mat-menu and mat-menu-item?

Tags: angular

In my angular app, i want to make a dynamic mat-menu with menu-item generate from an array. The menu and all item, icon, label display nice.
But when i click any menu item, haven't any event fire?

```html
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before">
  <span (mouseleave)="menuTrigger.closeMenu()">
    <div *ngFor="let f of funcList">
      <button (click)="this.trigger.emit({object: this.object, code: f.code})" 
               [routerLink]="f.router_link" 
               mat-menu-item>
        <mat-icon>{{f.icon}}</mat-icon>
        <span>{{f.label}}</span>
     </button>
    </div>
  </span>
</mat-menu>
```

[this is my mune items which are showing good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhGOs.png)

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing quote at the end of the click assignment. Is this the code you are actually using?

Comment: @R.Richards yes, i will update but in my app, have not any syntax error.

Comment: If i add some button without *ngFor, it work perfectly. Maybe angular not support to generate mat-menu-item with *ngFor or i missing something?

Comment: is it not building the buttons or does clicking on them dont work ?

Comment: @Nikolai Kiefer, all menu items, icons showing and look perfect, but have any event fire when i click menu and haven't any error in console log...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem is i was passing the list of menu items from parent component via @Input, so the menu items aren't showing by *ngFor.
If the list is fix like items = [1,2, 3, 4, 5...] the menu items are showing good.

Answer (score 0):

`(click)="this.trigger.emit({object: this.object, code: f.code}"` shouldnt be able to fire because of two reasons

1. it shouldnt be this.trigger.emit but just trigger.emit
2. you're not closing the bracket `(click)="this.trigger.emit({object: this.object, code: f.code})"`

Comment: 1. trigger is me EventEmitter which was declared in component.ts as Output and i have update to remove this but it's still not work. 2. Yes it my mistake when i post my code but in my project I'm already closed the bracket and haven't syntax error.

Comment: where are you checking if something happened. In the parent Component ?

Comment: because trigger is Output of EventEmitter so i handle it by something like this in HTML of parent app: 
<app-children (trigger)=parentHandler($event)></app-children>. 

For my issue, i already checked and found that, if function list is dynamic (i my case is pass from parent  or decalred and initial in contructor or ngOninit  of children) then no event fire when i click menu-item.
If function list is declared with fix values (like this pulic funcList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) then all menu-item work... 
Still don't know why.

Comment: Anyone of you can help me with this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67663139/click-function-not-being-called-for-a-mat-menu-with-items-generated-with-ngfor